# grep with variable

Tags: grep, sudo

I am trying to create a script to monitor all logins using sudo, both success and failure.

Right now, I have:

```
set tdate = $(date "+%b %d")
set attempted_su_log = /var/log/suattempts

cat /var/log/secure | grep $tdate | grep 'servername su' >> $attempted_su_log
```

How can I grep the current date from /var/log/secure, so I only get entries from the day they occurred?

When I run

```
cat /var/log/secure | grep 'Mar 18' | grep 'servername su'
```

from the command line, I get the results I need, but I'm not sure how to write the script to grep with the current date, set as the $tdate variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote the argument to grep: `grep "$tdate"`. This is
because `$tdate` expands to two whitespace-separated words, which in
turn get passed to grep as two arguments, unless the double quotes are added.

Your script could be improved to remove the useless use of cat, and to
call grep only once:

```
</var/log/secure grep "$tdate.*servername su" >>"$attempted_su_log"
```

Answer (score 1):

`tdate` has a space in there.  So, grep treats the second part of `tdate` as a filename.  You will need to enclose `$tdate` in double quotes to prevent that.  Your command should look like:

```
cat /var/log/secure | grep "$tdate" | grep 'servername su' >> $attempted_su_log
```